# Laravel - Show error on the same page if login credentials are wrong

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and i am working on login page in which i want throw error below input tags if login credentials are wrong. I have written some code and everything is working fine but errors are not showing.

Have a look at what I have done.

In Controller:

```
public function login(Request $req) {

    $email = $req->input('email');

    $password = $req->input('password');

    $checkLogin = DB::table('admin')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();

    if(count($checkLogin) > 0) {
        echo "Login Successfull";
    }
    else {
        // echo "Login Failed!";
        return Redirect::route('admin-login')->with();
    }
}
```

In View:

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

@if ($errors->has('email'))

<span class="help-block">

<strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>

</span>

@endif
```

In Route:

```
Route::post('admin-login-result','AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin-log');
```

Thanks

Comment: You should try laravel auth https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one in your else block

```
Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
```

In view file use like this

```
@if($errors->any())
  <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

Refer this link for more details https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-53-form-input-validation-rules-example-with-demoexample.html

Comment: After writing this code in Controller file. what to write in view page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use for login users

```
Auth::login($user);
```